# making top-level patterns monomorphic

Tags: haskell, type-inference, hlist

```
import Control.Lens

-- is there a way I can write top-level definitions
-- in an arbitrary order like
px = proto & _1 %~ asTypeOf '2'
py = proto & _2 %~ asTypeOf "2"
proto = (undefined, undefined)

-- but have types inferred like the following:
(qx,qy,qroto) = case (undefined, undefined) of
  qxy -> (qxy & _1 %~ asTypeOf '2',
          qxy & _2 %~ asTypeOf "2",
          qxy)
```

I get the desired `qroto :: (Char, [Char])`, but `proto :: (t, t1)` is too general. More importantly, this leads to `px :: (Char, t)` instead of `qx :: (Char, [Char])`.

The larger problem is that I am trying to make it possible to reduce the type annotations needed with the third argument to [Data.HList.Variant.mkVariant](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HList-0.3.4.1/docs/Data-HList-Variant.html#mkVariant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(dx,rx) = ((), rroto & _1 %~ asTypeOf '2')
(dy,ry) = ((), rroto & _2 %~ asTypeOf "2")
rroto = const (undefined, undefined) (dx,dy)
```

This forces `rx,ry,rroto` to be monomorphic:

```
> :t px
px :: (Char, t)
> :t qx
qx :: (Char, [Char])
> :t rx
rx :: (Char, [Char])
> :t rroto
rroto :: (Char, [Char])
```

To "trigger" the monomorphism restriction you have to use a set of definitions which is mutually dependant. That is, every equation must depend on the others. Above, we obtain this by adding `dx,dy` to force the dependency.

---

A simpler way to achieve the same effect:

```
rx = rroto & _1 %~ asTypeOf '2'
ry = rroto & _2 %~ asTypeOf "2"
rroto = const (undefined, undefined) (rx,ry)
```

Comment: Thanks. This does what I asked, but passing values in both directions to ensure we have a cycle is a bit annoying. Binding an implicit parameter `?proto` in main, and using`-XNoMonomorphismRestriction` doesn't have that fault, but it has other issues (lack of sharing and main gets cluttered).